# how I assign from pointer of array to array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have pointer array like this;

char* ptr[2]={"my","phone"};
char array[20];

I want to assign *ptr[1] to in array . how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The following will copy "phone" into 'array'. Not sure that's what you really want to do, though -

```
strcpy(array, ptr[1]);
```

Note that '*ptr[1]' is not ptr[1], obviously. '*ptr[1]' is like saying "dereference the pointer that's contained in the second place of the array named ptr". ptr[1] is a string (a buffer terminating with a '\0' byte), and its type is char *; when you dereference that, you get a char - 'p' in this case.

You also didn't say what exactly you mean by 'assign', so I assumed you meant you wanted the first element from the 'ptr' array copied, which calls for 'strcpy'. If you actually want the first character from ptr[1] (meaning, 'p') in array[0], you can do this:

```
array[0] = *ptr[1];
```

Comment: Hangman is a classic paper and pencil guessing game. Write a C program
to develop a basic Hangman game. The program contains several words in a
two dimensional array and the program picks a random word in this array with
srand and rand commands, but don’t display on the screen. Also, the program
contains row of empty stars and guesses left parameters in the console. The
user tries to guess this random word. Also the user will enter one letter at a
time. Each letter must be compared with the word and the correct guess must
be placed in the place of the star.

Comment: If the user enters 5 wrong letters, ‘Game over’
will be displayed on the screen. On successful guess of word, ‘Congratulations,
right word!’ is displayed. The program also shows a parameter that how many
times you find the correct word in a play.

Comment: The word database is given as
follows. The example output screen is shown below.
const char* word_database[] = {"literature", "scholar",
"enormous", "influence", "publication", "pioneer", "telephone",
"orchestra", "teacher", "member", "final", "phonograph",
"executed", "oldest", "people", "requiring", "screwdriver",
2"intelligent", "different", "striking"}
Note: You can use string functions and memcpy function.
Figure 1: Example output screen of the hangman game.

Comment: you mean, can I do your homework? This isn't how this site works buddy

Comment: I am so sory .your right. I try lots of time but I do not do . so I write like this . again I am so sory